# Voltage Level Shifter Sustained Overvoltage Protection

Tags: level-shifting, over-voltage-protection

## Situation

We have a board that accepts 3.3V signals for SPI, JTAG, UART and similar protocols.
We want to connect to interfaces on other boards that operate in the 1.8V to 5V voltage range and hence need to build a voltage adapter / translator.

A bidirectional voltage level shifter like the [TXS0108E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0108e.pdf?ts=1678219044322&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTXS0108E) would work well, but they all have the limitation V_CCA < V_CCB, which would limit us to 1.8V <-> 3.3V OR 3.3V <-> 5V.

Additionally, there is a real danger of connecting to unexpected voltages of up to 24V. Of course, one could measure the voltage before connecting, but life happens.

## Question

Is there a simple way to protect our circuits from such overvoltages without affecting signal quality (explicitly sustained, since the TXS already features protection against transients / ESD events)?

I don't expect currents to be very high, since we are dealing with data lines.
My idea would be a current limiting resistor and a Zener diode to create a short to ground in case of overvoltage.

[image]

[Link to circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAncQqsDQkCjx5w-KMjhsAXoOGCMKWSL4DFAEwYAzAIYBXADYAXJlIYA7BhzYBzJfMVCR2NOMhsAbtyooavHqIEqKl9BaGxSCMjIvEDXaAQbL0EQsH9nIKg2AHc7FQowRTy3LgQCgPyHBFiweElbUsqBBpB01zZsQhFmvIQaGnAhNoB7EBFCfuDIUmQQQmgJ2lGWpaondqcQADEIKiYXFxYQADUho21rBjYgA)

1. Does this work as long as the diode does not exceed its power
   rating?
2. Does this impact the signal quality in a meaningful way? We
   have an SPI interface that supports up to 42MHz and UART should work
   with a baudrate of 115200 (So, ~1.8MHz).

Comment: A Zener diode does not create a short to ground; it limits the voltage but, that voltage will rise if more current is put through it. Does this affect how you think about things and what the potential power dissipation in the Zener might be? Hint - a 1 kohm resistor in series with a line carrying SPI at 48 MHz is probably going to render it useless but, others may have a different opinion. Why not try it and see.

Comment: Funny thing is, most people here ask about why bi-dir level shifters like the TXS0108E don't work well for them and cause more problems than solve, so it would likely not be a good general purpose level shifter for all kinds of arbitrary signals over arbitrary cables of arbitrary lengths.

Comment: There are ways of protecting fast signals from sustained +/-24V, but usually prevention (physical or otherwise) is more economical.

Comment: @Andyaka Sure, the use of the term short is wrong here. To be honest, not only the resistor value, but also the general use of a Zener would be bad for the signal quality, right?
I seem to be able to find a lot of solutions for transient voltage spikes, but very little for sustained ones - is it just not feasible in general?

Comment: @Justme you are right, during my first search for the TXS0108E I only skimmed the questions here and it didn't seem too bad (and the datasheet kind of suggests a 'one size fits all' solution). Do you have any recommendations for feasible alternatives? I see quite a few solutions like this https://github.com/sparkfun/Logic_Level_Bidirectional that sport FETs, but was assuming that the TXS is more tuned to speed internally (having active circuity for flanks, smart pullups etc.).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany So your suggestion would be to roll without extra protection circuitry and just take care of not burning things in the first place? :D

Comment: No, my suggestion would be to add low-capacitance ESD protection as is typical on commercial high speed interfaces and use fine pitch connectors or whatever to prevent sloppy users from getting their grubby paws near the signal conductors. Probably will help signal integrity too.

Comment: Asking for recommendations what to buy are off-topic. But the SparkFun FET shifter is also unsuitable for same reasons, it will not level shift up and down, only to either up or down depending on which way you connect it, and high speed unidirectional signals like SPI, JTAG and UART will not pass through well through these FET shifters. Why do you insist on bi-dir translators for unidirectional signals? Isn't there standard logic chips that can interface your 3.3V system to any target voltage?